# How many points are there in $x \in \mathbb{Z}^d$ with $||x||_{\infty}=n, n \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I would like to find a closed formula in terms of $n$ and $d$.

Comment: Maybe $(2n+1)^d-(2n-1)^d$

Comment: number of elements with $||x||_{\infty} \leq n$  minus number of elements with $||x||_{\infty} \leq n-1$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How many ways can you select $d$ integers such that the maximum absolute value of these integers is $n(\neq0)$?

If $a$ is one of the integers selected, $|a|\le n$ so there are $2n+1$ choices for $a$. So we can pick $d$ such integers in $(2n+1)^d$ ways. But some of these selections will be such that every integer has absolute value less than $n$. The number of such selections is (counting as before) $(2n-1)^d$. So the required number of ways is
$$
(2n+1)^d-(2n-1)^d
$$